# Using an index twice in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to use a for loop where it looks through an array and tries to make sure the same element is not used twice.  For example, if $r or the random variable is assigned the number "3", my final array list will find the value associated with wordList[3] and add it.  When the loop runs again, I don't want $r to use 3 again.  Example output: 122234, where I would want something along the lines of 132456.  Thanks in advance for the help.

```
for($i = 0; $i < $numWords; $i++){
  $r = rand(0, $numWords);
  $arrayTrack[$i] == $r;
  $wordList[$r] = $finalArray[$i];
    for($j = 0; $j <= $i; $j++){
      if($arrayTrack[$j] == $r){
          # Not sure what to do here.  If $r is 9 once, I do not want it to be 9 again.
          # I wrote this so that $r will never repeat itself
          break;
      }
}
```

Edited for clarity.

Comment: Sidenote: `$arrayTrack[$i] == $r;` you're comparing instead of assigning.

Comment: Sample input and output please.

Comment: @MarkM So the sample input is the person enters in 9, so numWords = 9. wordList[14] is hardcoded at the moment as a, b, c... o.  So sample output currently will be abbdecfoi.  But I don't want there to be duplicates. So ideally "abcdefghi" in some random order.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, This is intentional because I want to reassign $r when $arrayTrack[$i] and $r are the same.  I think I am just confused as to how to reassign $r, or make it loop through the entire for-loop again so I don't get a duplicate.

Comment: It makes no sense though. `==` is used as a comparison. You are doing nothing with that comparison. You are literaly comparing `$arrayTrack[$i]` (not $arrayTrack[$j]...) and `$r`, then caring nothing about it.

Comment: Hard to tell what you're asking, and what your code is trying to do. You have a `break` in a loop that doesn't do anything. Input and output would probably clarify it. Don't you just want shuffle the array?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  I just want random to not be the same number over and over again.  For example, if $r is 9 once, I don't want it to be 9 again.  The purpose of implementing the arrayTrack is so that I can store the value $r and then compare it and if it is the same as before, then I want it to run the random function again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure you are over complicating things. Try this, using [**array_rand()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php):

```
$final_array = array();    

$rand_keys = array_rand($wordList, $numWords);

foreach ($rand_keys as $key) {
    $final_array[] = $wordList[$key];
}
```

If `$numWords` is 9, this will give you 9 random, unique elements from `$wordList`.

[**See demo**](http://codepad.org/9jpSkc0k)

Comment: Thanks a bunch and sorry for the confusion.  First time on stack overflow.

Comment: Wow. Its time for me to go to bed. I forgot all about array_rand(). +1 for you. Well played. =)

Answer (score 0):

```
$range = range(0, $numWords - 1); // may be without -1, it depends..
shuffle($range);
for($i = 0; $i < $numWords; $i++) {
  $r = array_pop($range);
  $wordList[$r] = $finalArray[$i];
}
```

I do not know why you want it.. may be it is easier to `shuffle($finalArray);`??

> So ideally "abcdefghi" in some random order.

```
$letters = str_split('abcdefghi');
shuffle($letters);
var_dump($letters);
```

ps: if you have `hardcoded` array `$wordList` and you want to take first `$n` elements of it and shuffle then (if this is not an associative array and you do not care about the keys)

```
$newArray = array_slice($wordList, 0, $n);
shuffle($newArray);
var_dump($newArray);
```

Comment: it is giving me an undefined offset error.  Does that mean I messed up my index somewhere?

Comment: @cae1um you have to show your original data, what do you have in $finalArray and what is $numWords.. Check if I'm right - you have `wordList[14]`, you want to take first $numWords elements from it and shuffle?

Comment: you are correct. I have wordList[14] and then I hardcoded each element at the time being.  Currently, $numWords = $_POST['num'] (so just a value the user enters).  $finalArray = array().  I am trying to have $r not be the same number twice.  I think I am making this a little harder than it is supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

You can try array_rand and unset

For example:

```
$array = array('one','two','free','four','five'); 
$count = count($array);
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)  
{ 
   $b = array_rand($array);
   echo $array[$b].'<br />';
   unset($array[$b]);
}
```

after you have brought the data in the array, you purify and simultaneously removing the memory array

Answer (score 0):

Ok... I have NO idea why you are trying to use so many variables with this.
I certainly, have no clue what you were using `$arrayTrack` for.
There is a very good chance I am mis-understanding all of this though.

```
<?php
$numWords=10;
$wordList=array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z');

$finalArray=array();
for ($i=0; $i<$numWords; $i++) {
    start:
    $r=rand(0,$numWords);
    $wordChoice=$wordList[$r];
    foreach ($finalArray as $word) {
        if ($word==$wordChoice) goto start;
    }
    $finalArray[]=$wordChoice;
}
echo "Result: ".implode(',',$finalArray)."\n";
```